# "Finish a book" vs. "finish with a book"

Tags: prepositions, difference

Could you tell me if there is any difference in meaning between *finish a book* and *finish with a book*? For example:

> When I **finish the book**, I can lend it to you.
>
> When I **finish with the book**, I can lend it to you

Comment: We often use "finish with" to mean "discard"; we might finish with a book without having read it to the end. To "finish" a book usually means to complete reading it.

Comment: 'Finish with' can also mean 'have no more use for' or 'have completed the particular task I was using it for' (that is, you were getting information from the book to write an essay which is now completed).